# Trouble reading ST600 data

Tags: soundtrap, hardware

We have a ST600 STD that was deployed for a period of 3months. We recently retrieved it and are unable to read the data from the device. When connected it just shows a red light. Internally and hardware-wise everything looks okay, no visible damage and no flooding.
If the SD card inside is connected to the computer (independently) and read via the soundtrap card reader, it doesn't show a list of SUD files. Does the card only work when connected via the device?
Any solutions are welcome.

Comment: Does it show files when SD card still inside Soundtrap? Maybe you did not record anything.

Comment: Confirm that you're using the latest SoundTrap host software to read it in?

Comment: To Walter's point re: recording anything - do you have a screenshot of the recording setting made prior to deployment that you could double check with?

Comment: We also had this issues a few times with ST 600 when the internal battery is very low. Apparently the only way to charge it is to leave the device connected to the computer for a couple of hours. Then the device appeared in the SoundTrap Host Software and we could retrieve the data.

Answer (score 3):

From the Soundtrap user guide

> SoundTrap uses a custom file system to maximise performance and reliability. This means
> the cards can only be read with the ‘SoundTrap Card Reader’ application supplied with the
> SoundTrap Host software. When inserting the memory cards into a PC you may receive a
> message like “Drive is not formatted, do you want to format it now?”. Agreeing to this will
> result in loss of data. Instead select ‘No thanks’ and run the SoundTrap card reader
> software.

This means:

- you can insert SD card into your PC
- you must be careful not to say OK to PC error message when inserting SD card.
- if SD card did not issue a warning when inserting to PC, that means that SD card is still formatted with PC style (most likely ExFat/Fat64) and Soundtrap did not write data onto SD card.

Edit: If all fails, it is worthwhile to open the uSD card with hexEdit (HxD). An IT specialist may help. This way you can read all the bits and bytes written to uSD. Obviously interpreting the data requires knowledge of what SoundTrap writes to disk.

Comment: Thank you! It does give a format drive message so I'm guessing it has managed to record something. We are using the latest software version too. With the SD card still inside the device when connected to the PC it doesn't show up on the host software.
I can post screenshots when in better connectivity off field.

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of SoundTrapHost will report no data if "Set Default File Save Location" in Tools menu is set to a non-existing folder. Make sure you are using the latest version from their website and you have an exisitng folder set for file save.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help your problem, but a  version of the SoundTrap software (4.0.16) was just released. You can find it here:
http://www.oceaninstruments.co.nz/downloads-beta/

Comment: Thanks, I will give it go with this version!